# PHP popen() path with quotes

Tags: php, popen

I'm trying to run an exe file with PHP's popen() function in Windows. Everything is perfect except if my .exe file has spaces in it's path.
So this works:

```
popen("start /b D:\\test.exe", r);
```

this doesn't:

```
popen("start /b D:\\path with space\\test.exe", r);
```

Normally in CMD when you want to do that you just put the path in quotes like: "D:\path with space\test.exe" and this works ok with exec() function but not with popen().

I've tried:

```
popen('start /b "D:\\path with space\\test.exe"', r);
```

but it doesn't work.

Anyone has any idea how to do this ?

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) function to add the spaces.